# How to copy/paste a baked sound f-curve?

Tags: graph-editor

I have done a bake sound to f-curve and now I want to use the same baked f-curve to multiple properties such as size, location, emitt etc...

But I can't edit the f-cure (TAB) or copy it. Do I have to bake the same sound for each property?!?

Or have I missed out on something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you bake the sound into one distinct property, like the scale of an empty you add for that purpose, and use it to drive all places where you need the sound f-curve. This way there is no duplicated data, and if you have to edit or change the sound you won't have to copy a bunch of animations every time.

You can also search for "bake action" from the spacebar menu to make the baked action into normal keyframes, and copy them around, but the driving method is better in my opinion.

Comment: I will try your solution as soon my 3 day rendering is done... Meanwhile I can red up on drivers :P

Answer (score 2):

If you want one f-curve to control many properties, typically drivers are the best way to handle this.

You could for example apply the fcurve to an empties X location, then use that to drive many other properties.